# How to get only xml from file in c#?

Tags: c#, xml

I have a problem with parsing file with XmlReader. I have a file containing info like this:

```
<Users>
<User>
<Email>email</Email>
<Key>23456</Key>
</User>
</Users>
asdfsof48f43uf489f3yf3y39fh3f489f3hf94[t]45.54tv,]5t
```

File contains xml values and then encrypted data from byte[] array.
The problem I've encountered is when i use:

```
 using (var reader = XmlReader.Create(fileName))
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                //parsing
            }
        }
```

I got  'System.Xml.XmlException' at line where encrypted bytes begin.
My question is: how to retrieve only xml part and only byte[] part?

Comment: why the `byte[]` array is not enclose with XML tag ?

Comment: Who controls the production of the file, and can you persuade them to produce a more useful file format, e.g. two separate files or put the final data within the XML?

Comment: Is file posted entire xml.  The portion posted is not well formed xml so without more info people are assuming the file is not valid.

Comment: Is it always a <Users> root node?

Comment: I think `XmlReader.ReadSubTree()` is a useful method here. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreader.readsubtree(v=vs.110).aspx. Using this you can read only the 'Users' tree and won't read beyond.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If in case the encrypted data is always the last line you can use below snippet to read only XML part of data given that the XML data is limited in size

```
var fileLines = File.ReadAllLines(@"c:\temp\file.txt");
var xmlFromFile = string.Join("", fileLines, 0, fileLines.Length - 1);
using (var reader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(xmlFromFile)))
{
    // Your logic goes here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do string parsing...

```
int start, end;
string myFile = File.ReadAllText("...");
start = myFile .IndexOf("<Users>");
end = myFile .IndexOf("</Users>") + 8;

myFile = myFile.Substring(start, end-start);
```

At that point you can load it into a xml document if you want.  This all depends on you being 100% sure about the file format.  This is a pretty fragile answer, so don't use it if you don't have a total trust in your input file.